# Zingchart-angularjs - get data on click event

Tags: angularjs, zingchart

I am using *Zingchart* into *AngularJs* app. I have a Bar chart where `scale X` defines list of `user_type` and in the `scale Y` defines the number of `users`. I need to get the `couple (X, Y)` in each bar click and doing a link to other view.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

After testing 3 or 4 events function, the right one is **node_click**:

```
$scope.myRender = {
    events: {
      node_click: function(p) {
        console.log(p.scaletext, p.value);
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $location.path("config");
        });
      }
    }
};
```

And I have to add zc-render="myRender":

```
<div zingchart id="chart-1" zc-json="myJson" zc-render="myRender" zc-width="100%" zc-height="600px"></div>
```